# Taking nav button out from hamburger menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a semi-progessive top navigation bar.

In the mobile viewport, it would only show logo and hamburger button.
(As you click the button, several navigation menu will come out as well as Log in and Sign up)

```
-------------------------------
Logo                          =
```

Once user hits the tablet viewport, I want Log in and Sign up menu to come out from the hamburger and stays beside the button.

```
--------------------------------------------
Logo                        LogIn  SignUp  =
```

The menus are tagged as li, of course under ul tag.
I was thinking about getting rid of li tag from those two buttons and take them out from ul, but I have no idea how to do so:(

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Add `signuploginclass` class name in signup and login li elements and then add the css code below in your stylesheet.

```
@media (max-width:500px){
    .signuploginclass{
      display: none;
   }
}
```

Comment: This will hide signup and login elements on mobile viewport at all.

Comment: @EricHobinYoo could you post your codes so I can help you?